# Can I use a Bluetooth USB driver/adapter with a Mac that has built-in Bluetooth to make switching devices easier?

Tags: keyboard, usb, bluetooth, kvm

I have a work and personal MacBook Pro and frequently switch between one and the other. All of my devices are connected through a USB-C docking station, so for the most part this is as easy as unplugging a cable from one computer and plugging it into another. However, when it comes to using any Bluetooth peripheral devices like keyboards, mice, trackpads, or headphones, it can be frustrating to switch them over to controlling the other device (especially since some devices aren't capable of storing multiple profiles, while others try to connect to multiple sources simultaneously as a "feature").

I'm wondering, if I just bought a simple USB Bluetooth adapter and plugged it into my USB-C hub, would I be able to pair my computer peripherals to the adapter rather than directly to my Mac?

Comment: That sounds like an interesting experiment. Just get a Mac compatible USB dongle from someplace with a liberal return policy. I am thinking that this is likely to work, but having never tried it, I will say "IMHO" and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bluetooth adapter that allows pairing to the device instead of the computer would be far more complex than the typical adapter one can pick up for less than $20 at any big box store.  It would also require drivers that would be different than a typical Bluetooth adapter.

What you could do is use wireless devices that are not Bluetooth.  I recall these being quite popular before Bluetooth caught on, and perhaps are still quite popular.  The ones I've seen use a USB wireless adapter that is permanently paired to the device it comes with.  This means buying new devices, and each device having it's own wireless adapter that will occupy a USB port.

Some of these non-Bluetooth devices are prone to interference, they use very simple protocols on the same frequencies used by so many other wireless in common use.  Bluetooth is "smart" enough to avoid most interference, which is why it is so popular.  I suspect that if you were to get a bunch of these simple wireless adapters plugged into the same computer that they may interfere with each other.

I recall seeing at least one vendor that use their own non-Bluetooth protocol that might offer what you are looking for.  I believe they can pair multiple devices to a single wireless receiver, which avoids the issue of needing many open USB ports to plug in an adapter for every device I mentioned above.  Pick any popular vendor of wireless computer peripherals and they likely offer something like I just described.

I've seen people use small programmable project computers to act as adapters for a variety of devices, perhaps someone offers software for these computers to do just what you want.  I've seen some of these computers have the hardware to act as a USB device to another computer, as well as built-in Bluetooth or a USB port for plugging in a Bluetooth adapter.  The Raspberry Pi series is one example of the kind of computer I'm talking about, there are others.

If you require that the devices be Bluetooth then the only solution I see is looking for a programmable project computer to act as the adapter.  Maybe someone solved this problem and offer the code for download.  Maybe you can be that someone that writes the code offers it for others to download.

Comment: Cool! So... doesn't sound like a simple task, but could be an interesting thing to play around with. I do actually already specifically use a Logitech keyboard so that I can use the USB receiver, and for now I just leave my Magic Trackpad plugged in, which keeps it both fully charged and always connected to the right computer. I was hoping for a good workaround for wireless headphones, especially ones with limited capacity for device support. Thanks for the insight!